# A generic algorithm for extracting product data from web pages

Tags: algorithm, data-extraction

*Preface: this might seem to be a very beginner-level question maybe stupid or ill-formulated. That's why I don't require a determined answer, but just a hint, a point, which I can start with.*

I am thinking of script, which would allow me to parse product pages of different online retailers, such as Amazon, for instance. The following information is to be extracted from the product page:

- product image
- price
- availability (in stock/out of stock)

The key point in the algorithm is that, once implemented, it should work **for any retailer, for any product page.** So it is pretty universal.

What techniques would allow implementation of such an algorithm? Is it even possible to write such a universal parser?

Comment: [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

Comment: I think that, rather than being a beginner-level question as such, it's the kind of thing beginners want to do because they do not yet have much experience with what sort of thing you can realistically do. You're asking for a holy grail here. It's not that hard (usually) to make a script adapted to a specific retailer, or maybe even a group of "very similar ones" (of course you could make several scripts to cover more retailers too), but "magically knowing where all the information is" without telling your program about it.. that sounds AI-complete

Comment: Once you succeed with such a universal script, please share with Google, guys will be really happy :)

Comment: Such information is typically formatted in a structured way, like a table. You could look for an image tag followed by a $ character followed by a numerical field (price) and another numerical field (amount). Start by analyzing the HTML code of several product pages and see what they have in common. Be ready to handle different layouts.

Comment: This is a hard problem. I'm talking post-doctoral research project hard. Like human level AI. It's not something you'll be able to do in any reasonable amount of time.

Comment: As others have mentioned, it's a very difficult problem. Your best bet is to try to find some software (that's being maintained and updated) where the work has already been done for a large number of websites. You are certainly not the first person to want that kind of data and I doubt you'll be the last, so the software should be out there.

Answer (score 1):

If the information on the product page is marked up in a structured, machine-readable way, e.g. using [schema.org microdata](http://schema.org/), then you can just parse the page HTML into a DOM tree, traverse the tree to locate the microdata elements, and extract the data you want from them.

Unfortunately, many sites still don't use such structured data markup — they just present the information in a human-readable form, with no consideration given for machine parsing.  In such cases, you'll need to customize your data extraction code for each site, so that it knows where the information you want is located on the page.  Parsing the HTML and then working with the DOM is still often a good first step, but the rest will have to be site-specific (and may need to be updated whenever the site changes its design).

Of course, you can also try to come up with heuristic methods for locating relevant data, like, say, assuming that a number following a `$` sign is *probably* a price.  Of course, such methods are also likely to occasionally produce incorrect matches (like, say, mistaking the "$10" in "Order now and save $10!" for a price).  You can adjust and refine your heuristics to be smarter about such things, but no matter how good you get at it, there will always be some new and unexpected cases that you haven't anticipated.

Comment: Clear, that's the way I was thinking about it. Just wanted to know if some useful frameworks or libraries already exist, that will make the task easier. Thank you for the answer.